# How can we extend the proof that Lie groups are orientable to parallelizable manifolds?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a Lie group with identity element $e$ and dimension $n$. I know we can take a non-vanishing $n$-form (call it $\omega$) on the vector space $T_eG$. For a Lie group, as we have an isomorphism between $Lie(G)$ (the set of left invariant vector fields on $G$) and $T_eG$, we can define an $n$ form $\chi$ on $G$ by the following process. Let $L_{g^{-1}}$ be the function denoting left multiplication of an element by $g^{-1}$. Then define:

$$\chi(g)=(L_{g^{-1}})^\ast \omega$$

and this is a non-vanishing $n$-form on $G$ as the map $L_{g^{-1}}$ is a diffeomorphism so takes non-vanishing forms to non-vanishing forms.

My question is can we extend this idea to all parallelizable manifolds? I understand from having read it somewhere that all parallelizable manifolds are orientable, so would this sort of idea work in the more general case, or do we have to use a different method?

Thanks

Comment: Well, what is the definition of parallelizable and what does this tell you?

Comment: The definition of parallelizable I have says that the tangent bundle $TM$ is isomorphic as a vector bundle to $M\times \mathbb{R}^n$, although I am still having trouble seeing how to link the tangent bundle to an orientation. I understand that the tangent bundle is always trivially orientable (I think I proved this by transferring charts from $M$ to $TM$ and checking the transition maps) giving us a non-vanishing $2n$ form on the tangent bundle. Can we somehow "restrict" this down from $M\times\mathbb{R}^n\to M$?

Comment: @JamesWhitley, the more intuitive (at least to me) definition of parallelizable is that the manifold $M$ admits a global (moving) frame $e_{1}, e_{2}, \ldots , e_{n}$. The frame does not have to have to be a coordinate frame, but it does specify a consistent orientation in each tangent space $T_{p}M$.  Given any set of your coordinates on $M$, one can easily find (if needed) a new and related set of coordinates so that the orientation of your corresponding coordinate frame $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{1}}, \ldots \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{n}}$ agrees with that of the global frame.

Comment: @JamesWhitley, the existence of a global frame also lends itself quite nicely to the "non-vanishing" top form argument needed for the manifold to be orientable.

Comment: Yes, $TM$ is always an orientable $2n$-manifold, but orientability of $M$ is a question of whether $TM$ is an orientable vector bundle on $M$.

Comment: Thankyou @THW, that definition is a more intuitively clear, and I think I see the argument now.

Comment: Also thanks @TedShifrin, that also helps answer another confusion I had about the different sorts of orientability (regarding as a manifold vs as a vector bundle)!

Comment: Can I ask you a question? Why can we take a non-vanishing n-form on ?